# Connecting to a web server in putty

Tags: putty

How do I connect to the localhost apache web server of the machine I'm connected through Putty in?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Test if the server is up? If so `telnet localhost 80` (or 443) will do.  But it will not guarantee the server is reachable remotely.  If you want to brwose the site use w3m or any other text based browser.  Without more information people here can't help you properly.

Comment: I need to be able to access phpmyadmin from the remote server. how can i configure it so i can view it in my browser?

Comment: It would have been helpful if you'd mentioned that in the first place. The process is described here: http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to access phpmyadmin which runs on the remote server, I'd suggest you use putty to create an ssh tunnel. This is described [here](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html).

You will need to create a "Local" tunnel from a Local Port of your choice (e.g. `1234` - just make sure the port number is larger than 1024) to destination `127.0.0.1:80` (or `127.0.0.1:443` if for some weird reason you are using https on localhost). You can save the tunnel with your putty session so it will be automatically created every time you connect to the remote server.

Then, just go to `http://127.0.0.1:1234` from your browser and you will be securely accessing the  phpmyadmin running on the remote server.

Comment: When I fill out the Destination and source port I'll need to use 127.0.0.1:1234?

Comment: Or is it the domain of the server i am connecting to? I am connecting to a domain. So would I need to fill in example.com:1234 for the destination?

Comment: The destination is the address/name and port of the server you want to connect to. So you will need to fill example.com:80 (HTTP) or example.com:443 (HTTPS) for accessing the web server running on example.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text-based browser like `w3m http://localhost/path/to/page`. You can also use `wget` to download the page content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text browser such as lynx, or URL fetcher such as curl or wget, or even telnet to your http port directly.